# Documentation for PyTorch .to('cpu') or .to('cuda')

Tags: python, pytorch

I've searched through the [PyTorch documenation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html), but can't find anything for `.to()` which moves a tensor to CPU or CUDA memory.

I remember seeing somewhere that calling `to()` on a `nn.Module` is an in-place operation, but not so on a tensor.

Is there a in-place version for `Tensor`s?

Where do I find the doco for `to()` for both `nn.Module` and `Tensor` (and possibly elsewhere)?

Answer (score 16):

You already found the documentation! great.

`.to` is not an in-place operation for tensors. However, if no movement is required it returns the same tensor.

```
In [10]: a = torch.rand(10)

In [11]: b = a.to(torch.device("cuda"))

In [12]: b is a
Out[12]: False

In [18]: c = b.to(torch.device("cuda"))

In [19]: c is b
Out[19]: True
```

Since `b` is already on gpu and hence no change is done and `c is b` results in `True`.

However, for models, it is an in-place operation which also returns a model.

```
In [8]: import torch
In [9]: model = torch.nn.Sequential (torch.nn.Linear(10,10))

In [10]: model_new = model.to(torch.device("cuda"))
In [11]: model_new is model
Out[11]: True
```

It makes sense to keep it in-place for models as parameters of the model need to be moved to another device and not `model` object. For tensor, it seems new object is created.

Answer (score 10):

I'm still learning to navigate the documentation site (the search isn't great).

Here's what I found:

#### [`torch.Tensor.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to)

The tensor version either returns:

- `self` if the tensor is in the target format already, or,
- a copy of the tensor in the target format

There is no in-place version listed.

---

#### [`torch.nn.Module.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.to)

The documentation implies that this is an in-place operation:

> Moves and/or casts the parameters and buffers.